# Help with the Moles syntax for testing private method with generics

Tags: moles, pex-and-moles

I've got a signature for a method that looks like this:
private IEnumerable BuildCustomerUpdatePlan(List localCacheChangedCustomers, List crmChangedCustomers){}

When I look at the moled object, the syntax (IntelliSense) of how to call the method and test itis absolutely confusing to me and every time I give it a shot, I get compilation errors. I've looked through the basic tutorials provided on MSFT's site, but I simply don't get how to test a private method using Moles or how to deal with the return type and multiple parameters.

Unfortuantely I've been unable to find other good HOWTO's or threads demonstrating a more complex sample than just working with a simple Add() method that spits out an INT and accepts an INT. :(

Tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your testing project, first make sure you add a Moles assembly corresponding to the assembly-under-test. You'll also want to add an `using` statement of the assembly-under-test with `.Moles` appended so you can use the moled assembly.

Moles changes the names of the classes and methods to the form `M[Original Class Name].[Original Method Name][typeof param1][typeof param2]...`. In your case a detour for that method could look like `MClass.BuildCustomerUpdatePlanListList = (List x, List y) => { [code]};`. That defines an anonymous method that takes two `List`s as parameters and you'd put whatever code wanted in the function. Just make sure that you return an `IEnumerable` in that anonymous method.

Here's an example using Moles to detour `Directory.GetFiles`:

```
using System.IO.Moles;
[assembly: MoledType(typeof(System.IO.Directory))]
...
    MDirectory.GetFilesStringString = (string x, string y) => new string[0];
```

Since the `Directory` class is a member of `System.IO` I use `using System.IO.Moles;` to specify that I want to use moled members of the assembly.

Moles requires you to specify the types Moled: `[assembly: MoledType(typeof(System.IO.Directory))]` does the job.

Finally, `Directory.GetFiles` takes two strings as parameters and returns a string array. To detour the method into returning the equivalent of no files found, the moled method just returns `new string[0]`. Curly braces are needed if you want multiple lines in the anonymous method and, if not detouring a void method, a return statement that matches the type the original method would return.